# How can I test a method which calls error() with specs2?

Tags: scala, specs2

I'd like to make a test for a method which calls `error()` in it.

`IntEmptyStack.top` is what I want to test with specs2:

```
abstract class IntStack {
  def push(x: Int): IntStack = new IntNonEmptyStack(x, this)
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def top: Int
  def pop: IntStack
}
class IntEmptyStack extends IntStack {
  def isEmpty = true
  def top = error("EmptyStack.top")
  def pop = error("EmptyStack.pop")
}
```

And here's the specs I wrote so far:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.specs2.runner.JUnitRunner
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class IntStackSpec extends Specification {

  "IntEmptyStack" should {
    val s = new IntEmptyStack
    "be empty" in {
      s.isEmpty must equalTo(true)
    }
    "raise error when top called" in {
      s.top must throwA[RuntimeException]
    }
  }
}
```

The error occurs in line 13, `"raise error when top called" in {`. The error message is `value must is not a member of Nothing`. I think Scala infers `s.top` as Nothing, not an Int as defined in the abstract class. In this case, how can I write a test without any errors?

Thanks for any comments/corrections to this question.

Example Reference: [Scala By Example](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaByExample.pdf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that scala (and Java) allow subclasses to return more-specific types than  superclasses in overridden methods. In this case, your method `IntEmptyStack.top`'s return-type is `Nothing` (which is a sub-type of `Int` because `Nothing` is at the bottom of the type hierarchy.

Evidently spec's implicit conversions necessary for you to write code like `a must throwA[X]` do not apply when the type of `a` is `Nothing`

Change your declarations in `IntEmptyStack`as follows:

```
def top: Int = error("EmptyStack.top")
def pop: Int = error("EmptyStack.pop")
```

Alternatively, of course, you could allow the fact that the *correctness* of your logic is being **proven by the type system**. That is, it is not possible to get an element which is at the top of an empty stack: the return type is `Nothing`! No tests are necessary.